# Internal consistency and other item analyses

Tags: item-response-theory

Is it appropriate to run internal consistency and other item analyses on a test that has questions with different response formats. To be clearer, all questions have a likert response, but some are 5 levels, some are 7 levels. Should I convert them all to a standard before I run any of the above mentioned analyses?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very difficult to question to answer.  It really depends on so much information that is not included in your question.  Please search this site and reference other material on psychometrics and IRT.  I am not really sure why this question is tagged in IRT, because it is of a more general nature.

In short, if it is appropriate to add the items together and arrive at a summed score (which it appears you are going to do), then it is probably appropriate to do some correlational analysis and estimate internal consistency with Cronbach's alpha.  The first part of this paragraph is a big "if", though. This is a very big field, and I encourage you to read extensively on the topic.